# Нужна ли запятая перед КАК? (3)

Tags: пунктуация, как

1. *Надежны как кирпич.*
2. *Экологичны как дерево.*

Comment: @oleedd  Поскольку автор вопроса изначательно не связывал две фразы в одно предложение, может, лучше поставить точку между ними или хотя бы написать вторую с большой буквы, как делают в справочниках?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Да, хорошо, просто там вообще запятая была.

Comment: @oleedd  Я имел в виду, что у автора вопроса вообще был союз "и", связывающий две фразы в кавычках.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Знаю, но shampar поставил запятую, а то, что одно предложение, влияет, ведь параллелизм тогда, не хотелось проходить мимо, потому что решение может быть разным, особенно если фразы не связаны. Мне кажется, что точки с запятой достаточно (можно понять, что две отдельные фразы), но точка лучше. Можно ещё больше разделить, параллелизм может быть даже в соседних предложениях.

Comment: Наталья. Чтобы дать однозначный ответ, нужно знать, где и в каком виде используются эти фразы. Опишите ситуацию и приведите контекст (2-3 предложения с участием рассматриваемых конструкций).

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Но можно дать все варианты, и это даже лучше, если автору вопроса не нужно использовать эти фразы. Мне кажется, что во втором примере нельзя без запятой.

Comment: @oleedd Выдумывать варианты с запятой неохота. Это будут примеры, в которых качества чего-то сравниваются с конкретными характристиками кирпича и дерева. В самостоятельном виде обе фразы я написал бы без запятой. Экологичность материала/изделия не сравнивается с такокой у дерева, а приравнивается (ну, как мне кажется), становится "деревянной", и оборот является частью сказуемого.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец *Экологичность материала/изделия не сравнивается с такокой у дерева* — а мне кажется, наоборот. Во втором примере вижу исключительно сравнение. Как проверить? Попробовать заменить наречием. "Как кирпич" — "прочно".

Comment: @oleedd  "Как дерево" — "чисто", "не вредно", "по-деревянному" :))

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Дело в том, что у кирпича есть сущностное свойство прочности, даже напоминает фразеологизм. А вот у дерева нет сущностных свойств чистоты и невредности. Бывают ядовитые деревья, то есть вредные. А "по-деревянному" здесь вообще не в тему. Если читать без ударения на "экологичны", мне даже немного режет слух.

Comment: @oleedd мои ":))" относились только к "по-деревянному". Неправильно оформил. Но всё равно: имеют свойства дерева, отждествляются с ним.